# Apache Jmeter load testing on Mobile native app failing due to android device losing internet connection while on same network

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load test mobile app with Apache Jmeter but facing a typical problem. I have done all the required configuration like setting the domain, server name, port in Jmeter. I have also configured my android phone by installing Root CA file, setting the Host name with Jmeter system's IP,  port to 8080, IP settings to DHCP, Proxy to Manual but whenever both the system and android device are on the same Wifi network, android device is getting disconnected from the internet and the recording is getting stuck. So can somebody please help me on this.

Comment: I have changed the port to 8888 but still it's not working...

Comment: The primary problem is the internet connection for android device, whenever the system and the android device are on the same network the device is loosing it's connection. As per the Jmeter configuration Jmeter installed System IP has to be set as Host Name in the android device...so is this creating any problem....

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [JMeter Bug 59006](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59006) since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) default port for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) has been changed to `8888` in order to match the configuration which is being performed via [Recording Template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) so make sure that Android proxy port matches HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder port.
2. On Android versions after 7.0 ([Nougat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_7.0_Nougat_(API_24))) you might need to apply [extra configuration](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-nougat-charlesing-ssl-network-efa0951e66de) in your application [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).
3. If you don't have possibility to amend application source code - there is a possibility to add JMeter's certificate directly to Android [`/system/etc/security/cacerts/` file](https://blog.jeroenhd.nl/article/android-7-nougat-and-certificate-authorities)